# JBOSS AS 7 monitoring Paramaters

Tags: performance-monitoring, performance-tuning, jboss, performance-counters

We are using JBOSS AS 7 in standalone mode to run our web application. 
Our user base is around 1000 users and we have 4 instances of a JBOSS running on 4 RHEL6 machines behind a load balancer. sometimes, our users are facing website slowness . 
I tried to monitor the Linux server parameters - the RAM usage and processor usage is very less. I tried to monitor JBOSS parameters using Jolokia and I couldn't find the root cause of this slowness. 
What are the primary parameters that we have to look in JBOSS ? and whats the exact JMX parameter so that I can check using Jolokia

this is the output of 'top' command in one of the Linux server during slowness.

*load average: 0.10, 0.16, 0.12*
These numbers are not bad right  ?

I couldn't connect JConsole from a windows machine to these Linux servers.  I tried very hard but no luck. These Linux servers dont have a GUI installed.

Server Specs :

- OS : RHEL 6 JBoss AS 7
- RAM : 12 GB in each server
- Heap Memory allocated : 8GB in each server
- HTTP threads configured : 200 in each server

Answer (score 0):

I used JBoss in the past and indeed those numbers are not bad. Quite the opposite, they are great!

Anyway, I recommend you monitor your JBoss infrastructure with a monitoring solution. I used Pandora FMS (http://pandorafms.com ) and its [JBoss plugin](http://library.pandorafms.com/index.php?sec=Library&sec2=repository&lng=es&action=view_PUI&id_PUI=231).